# Is there a way to use \nopagebreak globally, between two or more known words?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking

I'm looking for a way to define a couple of well-known word pairs that should never be split between pages, even if that means leaving a slightly awkward blank space at the end of the paragraph. I know I can manually hunt those instances and add `Hello\nopagebreak World`, however, I'd like to define those instances once and not worry about it. In similar fashion hyphenation does with `\hyphenation{iOS macOS SwiftUI UIKit}` in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `Hello\nopagebreak World` would produce `HelloWorld`  but you could do what you want in luatex. `Hello\nopagebreak\ World` would prevent a page break after the line with `Hello World` even if both words  are on the same line.

Comment: Have you tried simply putting a `~` between the two words?  That is a more general "do not break", and I've never seen it break anywhere.  Of course, this might be more than is needed or desirable in other environments.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That would mean I'll have to hunt down all the possible instances where the two words are next to each other and add a `~` in-between? If so, I'm trying to avoid exactly that and instead list once all the words and let LaTeX do its thing. A lot like the way `\hyphenation` works.

Comment: @Rad'Val I would use `~` and prevent line break (so naturally prevent page break)  `Hello\nopagebreak\ World` always prevents a page break even if `Hello World` is on the same line. Doing what you ask is tricky even if you add a command at that point, doing it globally is not possible except possibly  with luatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I did just that. I was not aware of `~`. Also, gave up trying to do this globally as I initially mentioned, it's over-optimization. I need to check each page of the book anyway because of other possible problems, so a final step while editing to insert `~` is not that bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new command:

```
\newcommand{\helloworld}{Hello\nopagebreak\ World}
```

Comment: Why would it not? It is hard to force, but in my tries it works...

Comment: actually it  does prevent a page break but if the line does not break at `\ ` it prevents  a page break after this line